# Skew one corner of image

Tags: css, transform, perspective, skew

I'm trying to skew one single corner of my div background as shown at the green checkmark in the image below:

[image]

In CSS3 I'm however unable to achieve that, skewing completely skews every corner. I just want to skew the bottom right corner to the left (say 25px) and maintain the perspective (as shown in the image above).

```
 background-image: url('http://rtjansen.nl/images/stackoverflow.png');
-webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3eX5j/

My code is:

```
div {    
    width: 300px;
    height:80px;
    margin-left:40px;
    background-image: url('http://rtjansen.nl/images/stackoverflow.png');
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: Do you want a pure CSS3 solution?

Comment: I would like to stick as close to pure CSS3 as possible

Comment: I don't have a lot of time, but it seems possible. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8QhBb/2/) is what you want, isn't it? It's a quick hack based on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) on perspective. I know it needs work, sorry.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

All you need to do is to think in 3d:

```
div {    
    width: 300px;
    height:80px;
    margin-left:40px;
    background-image: url('http://rtjansen.nl/images/stackoverflow.png');
    -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-25deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
    -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-25deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: left center;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eX5j/3/)

explanation: you are rotating the element towards you in the upper part. But, the perspective (handled though the transform origin, it's a function !) makes the left hand rotation not to translate in an horizontal movement.

See how can be controlled what is the final size

[fiddle with multiple options](http://jsfiddle.net/3eX5j/6/)

Comment: @Kroltan Thanks ! Happy that you like it !

Comment: there's just one problem with this solution, because it increases the width of the image, rather than decreasing it (in the bottom).

any idea how to accomplish this whilst maintaining the width?

Comment: Play with the point where you apply the transform. Added example. (with un-transformed div to compare)