# How can I skew one side of a div and then replicate it and skew a different side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, skew

Suppose I have a div:

```
div {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 500px; 
    background: blue; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

[image]

And I want it to become two mode - [skew](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) to each side -

[image]

Here is the base form - http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/neybabgj/

How could I get the above two forms?

**Update :**

If it required using JavaScript - do it.

Comment: You can't make two divs out of one without using JavaScript or some other dynamic language. You need to pick one or the other, or add another div.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D : what is not clear ? just get the div as the two attached forms ...

Comment: This is a hammer to crack a nut! However you might want to do it like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069704/skew-one-corner-of-image. But I'd stick with triangles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748387/how-to-bevel-the-corner-of-a-block-div/16748949#16748949

Comment: @TylerH not completely true. You can create new block elements by using :before and :after pseudo-classes

Comment: @denisol Correct, but I don't think that's what URL87 is trying to do here. At least, it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: @TylerH I am assuming he needs the shape, as he mentioned "forms", hence my answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="crop">
    <div class="skew"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.crop {
    width: 492px;
    height: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.skew {
    display: block;
    height : 100px;
    width : 500px;
    background : blue;
    margin : 0 auto 0 32px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg);
}
.skew:after {
    height : 100px;
    width : 500px;
    background : blue;
    margin : 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -120px;
    content:'';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neybabgj/7/

Answer (score 4):

[**JSiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/neybabgj/6/)

**CSS**

```
div {
    height : 100px;
    width : 500px;
    background : blue;
    margin : 10px auto;
    position: relative;
}
div:first-child:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:100%;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    content:'';
    border:50px solid blue;
    border-top-color:transparent;
    border-left-color:transparent;
}

div:nth-child(2):after {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    content:'';
    border:50px solid blue;
    border-bottom-color:transparent;
    border-right-color:transparent;
}
```